# Can I perform HTML validation on an asp:dropdownlist?

Tags: html, asp.net, validation

Is there a way to use HTML validation (not `asp:RequiredFieldValidator`) on an `asp:dropdownlist`? I have already tried this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ExpenseLineTypeDdl" required="required" initialvalue="0" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">  
     <asp:ListItem Value="0">Please Select a Type</asp:ListItem>    
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I'd like it to work similar to this (except for an `asp:dropdownlist`):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to get rid of `{initialvalue="0"}` and set the initial listitem's `{value=""}`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ExpenseLineTypeDdl" required="required" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">  
      <asp:ListItem Value="">Please Select a Type</asp:ListItem>    
</asp:DropDownList>
```