# Enable Required Field Validation In Only One Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, textbox

i am developing application in asp.net c#, in that i have a problem .
the problem is
i have three fields in a asp.net page, in that it having Bank Name, Branch, and IFSC Code, these three is mandatory to fill when i click save button,

but when i click search & clear button also it should ask to fill these fields.
how to restrict this when click other buttons

"please fill in this field"..

[image]

suppose if i search sbi bank only, it asks to enter every field.

**MY CODE**
    
        
           
              
                    Enter Bank

```
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
               Enter Branch</label>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtBranchName" runat="server" type="text" CssClass="form-control" PlaceHolder="Enter Branch" required />

          </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
               Enter IFSC Code</label>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtIFSCCode" runat="server" type="text" CssClass="form-control" PlaceHolder="Enter IFSC Code" required />
          </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
        <br />
        <br />
<table border="0px" cellpadding="4px" cellspacing="4px" align="center" width="180px">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" ValidationGroup="valInsert" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" ToolTip="Save" CssClass="btn btn-success" />
      </td>
      <td>
     <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="btnClear_Click" ToolTip="Clear / Refresh" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
      </td>
<td>
  <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" ValidationGroup="valInsert" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" ToolTip="Search" CssClass="btn btn-success" /></td>
    <td>
 <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick="return PrintPanel();" ToolTip="Print" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: remove ValidationGroup from other button .

Comment: hi i removed but still it asks please fill in this fields for all button click

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to put `formnovalidate` in your search button code

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" ToolTip="Search" CssClass="btn btn-success" formnovalidate  />
```

Comment: hi @Ravi i want to validate dropdownlist in asp.net, i don't know how to validate dropdown instead of text box using required. can you help me.

Comment: check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31878626/html5-required-attribute-on-aspdropdownlist

Comment: hi @Ravi please click the following link, i want to show the message like this in drop down, but your link does not,                                     https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSNK72jXmsYj_r9X6uAvEfTP7h0w--jZcz7rO1-G0-SJmU_urPYkw

Comment: @Surya this kind of validation works for textbox not for dropdownlist

Comment: thanks @Ravi, finally i got it -  [html5 validation on asp:dropdownlist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296146/html5-validation-on-aspdropdownlist)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Validation Group in ASP.net

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomer" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvName" runat="server"
                                                            ControlToValidate="txtCustomer" ForeColor="Red"
                                                            ToolTip="Please enter name" ValidationGroup="Validate" Display="Dynamic">* Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="btn  btn-default" runat="server" Text="Save" ToolTip="Save Record" ValidationGroup="Validate" OnClick="btnSave_Click"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnClear" CssClass="btn  btn-default" runat="server" Text="Clear" ToolTip="Clear / Refresh" OnClick="btnClear_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnClose" CssClass="btn  btn-default" runat="server" Text="Close" ToolTip="Go To Main form." OnClick="btnCancle_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery/javascript for validations.

Write button search and save click events in jquery and validate as you like.

```
$('#btnSave').click(function(){
//code for required field validation
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The property of search and  clear button ( causes Validation ) ..you should make it false  ;)

Comment: this should be in the comment.